# Wepback - Include a script tag if environment is set to production

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

My issue is this

https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto/issues/46

or - how do I get webpack to include a script tag into the HTML based off of my environment? I only want a certain script tag to be included if I'm running in production.

Here is what my current webpack file looks like (I'm using webpack 2).

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const VENDOR_LIBS = [
  'axios', 'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-apollo', 'prop-types'
];

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './client/src/index.js',
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader"
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader"
            }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {limit: 40000}
          },
          'image-webpack-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './client/src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

Comment: It could be helpful to know what this script tag is for and why you need it only for production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack always looks for a `webpack.config.js` file so you must do the following configurations to make it dynamic:

**package.json**

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --env=dev",
"prod": webpack -p --env=prod
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = function(env) {
  return require(`./webpack.${env}.js`)
}
```

Setting the `--env=[env]` flag is key.

I then had two different webpack files. One called `wepback.dev.js` and one called `webpack.prod.js`. Based on the `package.json` command it would run which ever. Then I had created two different index.html files - `index.prod.html` and `index.dev.html`. Inside of those I included any scripts I needed for each environment.

I'm using webpack 2. In each of the files my `plugins` area looks as so:

**webpack.dev.js**

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: './client/src/index.dev.html'
  })
]
```

As you can see in this example, my `webpack.dev.js` will output everything into my `index.dev.html` file. The prod version will mirror the same except using `prod`. To see the full `webpack` file look at the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Since Webpack configuration file **returns a JS object**, you might add a conditional statement (based on your environment or webpack variables) to add a [further item to `entry` property](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#object-syntax) before returning/exporting the configuration object.

```
const myWebpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './client/src/index.js',
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  }
};

if( /* production env, it depends on your  */) {
  myWebpackConfig.entry.productionScript = './my-production-script.js',
}

// Return config object
module.exports = myWebpackConfig;
```

An still more flexible approach consists of [exporting configuration function instead of an object](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-a-function-to-use-env) and specifying a custom building environment key via `--env` argument like `--env.production` when your run `webpack` command:

```
//my-webpack-config.js

// Configuration stuff...

module.exports = function(env) {
  // env is the "--env" argument your specified with webpack command
  if(env.production) {
    // Add your production scripts
  }

  return myWebpackConfig;
}
```

And then, When running webpack:

```
webpack --config ./my-webpack-config.js --env.production
```

A couple of tips to better set up your webpack config:

- [Webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge): merge webpack configuration objects
- [Webpack: building for production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/)